# Не работают переключатели radio button

Tags: html, вёрстка, checkbox, radio

Почему переключатели (radio button) не работают как нужно, по идее же активным должен оставаться только один элемент а сейчас они работают как checkbox.
Вот html

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" checked name="black" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="orange" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="blue" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="lightblue" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="green" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="gray" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="sand" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="white" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="pink" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" name="beige" class="color__item">
</form>
```

Comment: Имя должно быть одинаковое для всех инпутов. А вот значение `value` - разное.

Comment: @Moonvvell большое спасибо)

Comment: Потому что у вас везде разный name=""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас у всех `input` разные значения `name`

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" checked value="black" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="orange" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="blue" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="lightblue" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="green" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="gray" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="sand" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="white" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="pink" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
  <input type="radio" value="beige" name="rdbtn" class="color__item">
</form>
```